# Sequelize groupby proper typing with typescript

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I'd like to perform a GROUP BY query with Sequelize applying SUM and COUNT functions. The problem I'm facing is that new aggregate column names do not exist on the returned type. For example:

```
    const result = await SalesModel.findAll({
        attributes: [
            'partnerId',
            'status',
            [Sequelize.fn('count', Sequelize.col('value')), 'sales_num'],
            [Sequelize.fn('sum', Sequelize.col('value')), 'sales_value'],
        ],
        group: ['partnerId', 'status'],
        raw: true
    })
```

`result[0]` has `partnerId` and `status` attributes defined in the model, but doesn't have `sales_num` and `sales_value` attributes added by the GROUP BY query. What's the proper way to do typing here?

Answer (score 1):

Simply extend your existing model like

```
interface IExtendedSalesModel extends SalesModel {
    sales_num: number;
    sales_value: number;
}

...


const results: IExtendedSalesModel = await SalesModel.findAll({
        attributes: [
            'partnerId',
            'status',
            [Sequelize.fn('count', Sequelize.col('value')), 'sales_num'],
            [Sequelize.fn('sum', Sequelize.col('value')), 'sales_value'],
        ],
        group: ['partnerId', 'status'],
        raw: true
    })
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error in this case: const results: IExtendedSalesModel
Type 'SalesModel[]' is missing the following properties from type 'IExtendedSalesModel': sales_num, sales_value, date, partnerId, and 35 more.ts(2740)

Comment: I can do: const results = await SalesModel.findAll(..) as IExtendedSalesModel[], but then I loose all benefits of type checking.

Comment: ... sorry mate I didn't read your responses... till now! Did you find a solution for this? Looking at this now I can see at least one misstake in my answer. `.findAll` return's an array so the `const result...` declatration should at least be like `const result: IExtendedSalesModel[] = await...`